# Creating a folder Inside Mydocument Using Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am developing a Silverlight4 Application which has elevated permissions and is running out of Browser. I am acessing MyDocuments using this piece of code

```
if (Application.Current.HasElevatedPermissions)
{
   string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
}
```

Is it Possible to Create subfolder inside MyDocuments.

Can any One give sample code for it

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This isn't actually a duplicate question so I'm not sure why some think it is.  I suspect its because the answer to your last question in this area placed you inches away from the answer to this one, a quick cusory look at some of the other objects in System.IO such as `Path`, `File` and `Directory` would have given you the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to manipulate *directories* on the file system, you will want to use the static methods of [System.IO.Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx).  One such method is [CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

check this: http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-videos/using-isolated-storage-in-silverlight/